# How do I get a date between two dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to filter some values and I need to know if they can be between two dates or not, but I could not create a SQL to do this.

I have the following date: `May 10 2010`.

I need to find if this date can be between two dates if I add some years to it.

**Example1**: can this date be between `January 15 2014` and `June 20 2014`?

Yes, because  `May 10 2014` is.

**Example2**: can this date be between `May 15 2014` and `June 20 2014`?

No, because `May 10 2014` and `May 10 2015` is not between this interval.

**Example3**: can this date be between `December 15 2013` and `June 20 2014`?

Yes, because  `May 10 2014` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky in SQL Server.  I think the best way is to normalize the dates to Jan 1, based on when the period begins.  Then you can safely use `datediff()` to add the appropriate year value.

Something like this:

```
select (case when dateadd(year, datediff(year, newdate, newstart), newdate)
                      between newstart and newend
             then 'Between' else 'NotBetween'
        end)
from (select (StartDate - datepart(dayofyear, startDate) + 1) as newstart
             (EndDate - datepart(dayofyear, StartDate) + 1) as newend,
             (TheDate - datepart(dayofyear, StartDate) + 1) as newdate
      from (select cast('2013-12-15' as datetime) as StartDate,
                   cast('2014-06-20' as datetime) as EndDate,
                   cast('2010-05-10' as datetime) as thedate
           ) dates
     ) dates;
```

Comment: Note that `CAST('2010-05-10' AS datetime)` will be October 5th in europe. Always use locale independent date literals. i.e. '20100510'

Comment: @adrianm . . . I am going to stick with ISO standard date formats and consider this a bug in SQL Server.  I'm probably in a minority on that opinion, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
declare @intervals table (StartDate date, EndDate date);
declare @date date = '2010-05-10';

insert into @intervals values
    ('2014-01-15', '2014-06-20'),
    ('2014-05-15', '2014-06-20'),
    ('2013-12-15', '2014-06-20');

select case when dateadd(year,year(EndDate)-year(@date),@date) 
                 between StartDate and EndDate
            then 'Yes'
            else 'No'
       end,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
  from @intervals;
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
     StartDate  EndDate
---- ---------- ----------
Yes  2014-01-15 2014-06-20
No   2014-05-15 2014-06-20
Yes  2013-12-15 2014-06-20
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following approach:

- if your date range start date and end date have both the same year, then check if the date with replacing the year with the year of the range falls between your range;
- if your date range end year is exactly one year more than your date range start year, then check if either the date with replacing the year with the year of the range start date falls between your range or if the date with replacing the year with the year of the range end date falls between your range;
- if your date range end year is at least 2 years more than your date range start year, then it will always work

You might though get into trouble with the 29th of February

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
DECLARE @input datetime ='May 10 2010'

set @input = (select dateadd(year, 4, @input))



select * from T
where   @input >= 'January 15 2014'
              and @input <= 'June 20 2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this will be to check using DateDiff.

```
DECLARE @input datetime ='May 10 2014'

select case when DATEDIFF(d,'2014-01-15',@input) >=0 and  DATEDIFF(d,@input, '2014-06-20') >= 0 then 'yes' else 'No' end
```